# Is there an idiom that means "easy to destroy"?

Tags: idiom-request

Is there an idiom that means "easy to destroy"? I thought about the idiom "easy pickings", but I realized "easy pickings" is used for things that are easy to get, steal or refers to people who are easy to convince. Is there any similar expression that means "easy to kill, destroy, take care of"?

Comment: Could you give an example dialogue/scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot think of a perfect match, but these may come close:

- (A) pushover
- (A) sitting duck
- (To be) made of glass
- (To be *only*) flesh and blood
- (A) house of cards (does *not* refer to people, otherwise a match)

I'm sure there are more accurate alternatives, though.